# Difference between linux hash sum utilities and online string to hash utilities

Tags: hash, linux

When I go online and calculate a hash from a string on some generator website, no matter the algorithm or the website, it is always a different output than if I do `echo "password" | sha256sum` (or insert *sum there for corresponding algorithm). What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very possibly, the newline.

Try this instead:

```
$ echo -n "password" | sha256sum
```

The -n argument to echo tells it not to print a newline.

As you can see, this changes the hash:

```
$ echo "password" | sha256sum
6b3a55e0261b0304143f805a24924d0c1c44524821305f31d9277843b8a10f4e  -
$ echo -n "password" | sha256sum
5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8  -
$
```

Comment: This. But please note some versions of echo don't support -n and would print it literally. Check the behavior of yours first. If you need a portable way, use printf(1): `printf "%s" "password"'